# How to get distinct value from the list

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a List generated from Linq to Entities query. In which, I need to get a unique records based on `BibId`. I have tried changing the query but no help to get the unique records based on `BibId`.

**Query**

```
aa.NewBibContentsModel = (from x in db.BibContents

                                      where (x.TagNo == "245" && x.NormValue == aa.CurrentTitle) || (x.TagNo == "020" && x.NormValue == aa.CurrentISBN) || (x.TagNo == "022" && x.NormValue == aa.CurrentISBN)
                                      select new
            {
                BibId = x.BibId,
                Title = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.TagNo == "245" orderby a.Id ascending select a.NormValue),
                //Tit = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == line.BibId && a.TagNo == "245" && a.Sfld == "a" select a.NormValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                Author = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && splitted.Contains(a.TagNo) && a.NormValue != null select a.TagNo).FirstOrDefault(),
                ISBN = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.NormValue != null && (a.TagNo == "020" || a.TagNo == "022") orderby a.Id ascending select a.NormValue)
            }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new BibContentsModel
            {
                BibId = x.BibId,
                Title = string.Join(" ", x.Title),
                Author = string.Join(" ", (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.TagNo == x.Author orderby a.Id select a.NormValue)),
                ISBN = string.Join(" ", x.ISBN)
            }).ToList();
```

Any help to this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is know as *Distinct By*. [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has a function for it. The syntax would look like:

```cs
(from x in db.BibContentsNo == "022")
... // your query
}).AsEnumerable()
.DistinctBy(x => x.BibId) // <= MoreLinq
```

What is does is group the records by `BibId` and take the first element of each group.

You can download MoreLinq as a NuGet package.